# Show Arabic/Persian number if choice this number in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, date

After changing the site language to Farsi/Arabic, I still see the numbers in English on my site.
My font is completely Farsi, but the numbers are displayed in English.
Please advise that I have to do something special in Joomla 4 so that the numbers are displayed in Farsi/Arabic for me?

In fact, I should see the numbers in this way

[image]

But after changing to Farsi/Arabic, I still see English numbers like this

[image]